# How to appropriately migrate from componentWillReceiveProps to getDerivedStateFromProps when 'this' is being used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, static, react-lifecycle

I am trying to migrate my apps to do the React v16.3.* API, and it has been quite difficult to get rid of `componentWillReceiveProps`. I have components which are dependent on it and call the components other function in them.

Because `getDerivedStateFromProps` is static, I can't easily do this anymore and I need help on how to appropriately. For this case in particular, I have a timeout function that resets whenever new props are received. It currently is as follows:

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  clearTimeout(this.timeout)
  this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    this.dismiss(null, nextProps)
  }, nextProps.timer)
}
```

As you can see I have `this.timeout` and `this.dismiss` which I cannot access anymore once the change is made to `getDerivedStateFromProps`. How to I deal with this? Is there a way to change this to be a `getDerivedStateFromProps` static function or do I have to go about this a completely different way?

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps` is about whether or not state needs to be updated based on nextProps. There's no state updating in your example. If that is the case in your actual code, you could just use `componentDidUpdate` and operate on `this.props` instead of `nextProps`.

Comment: I hadn't realized I could use componentDidUpdate as a fine replacement for this particular case. Now I feel silly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Kyle mentions, this doesn't belong in `getDerivedStateFromProps`, but it might not be immediately obvious why you can safely do this in `componentDidUpdate`.

The reason you can is that you're only clearing and setting timers, which won't affect anything until after React has updated the DOM and finished executing. Hence, it makes no difference if you do this in the pre-render `componentWillReceiveProps` or the post-update `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate()
  clearTimeout(this.timeout)
  this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    this.dismiss(null, this.props)
  }, this.props.timer)
}
```

The React blog has some [example migrations](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#examples) that may prove helpful.

Comment: I hadn't realized that I could for that very reason. Needless to say, it does it's job perfectly. Thanks!